# Java library to calculate the semantic distance between two documents

Tags: library, java, nlp

I am looking for any java library that calculates the semantic distance between two documents.

I know that [WS4J](http://ws4jdemo.appspot.com) can calculate semantic distances using wikipedia data, also [lingpipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/read-me.html) has some NLP functions, so does [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/index.html), so does [Stanford NLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/) and also [Apache OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/)

However, most of them has primitives or can calculate distances between words. What I need here is a way to compute semantic distances between documents OOTB. Java library.

Comment: About what length, how many thousand/million characters?

Comment: yes, we can assume US-en UTF8 documents. thanks

Comment: I found SEMILAR: A Semantic Similarity Toolkit. It is a Java library as well as standalone application. This library can compute similarity (I assume that is semantic distance) between two texts (documents). You may check it out [here](http://deeptutor2.memphis.edu/Semilar-Web/public/semilar-app.html). *I recommend this on comment section rather than answer section because I have never tried using this library before).

Comment: yep, this is pretty much what I am looking for. I am gonna give it a try. thx